# Compare images and save in dynamodb aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Hi I want to write a lambda function which will work like.  I have two folder in  s3 bucket . in  1st box there are "owner"  and 2nd have random pictures. I want to compare all pictures with owner and then save in dynamodb with owner name against everypicture . Atm I am lost in API of face detection and doing some thing  like this

```
    BUCKET = "ais-django"
KEY = "20180530105812.jpeg"
FEATURES_BLACKLIST = ("Landmarks", "Emotions", "Pose", "Quality", "BoundingBox", "Confidence")


def detect_faces(bucket, key, attributes=['ALL'], region="eu-west-1"):
    rekognition = boto3.client("rekognition", region)
    response = rekognition.detect_faces(
        Image={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Name": key,
            }
        },
        Attributes=attributes,
    )
    return response['FaceDetails']


for face in detect_faces(BUCKET, KEY):
    print
    "Face ({Confidence}%)".format(**face)
    # emotions
    for emotion in face['Emotions']:
        print
        "  {Type} : {Confidence}%".format(**emotion)
    # quality
    for quality, value in face['Quality'].iteritems():
        print
        "  {quality} : {value}".format(quality=quality, value=value)
    # facial features
    for feature, data in face.iteritems():
        if feature not in FEATURES_BLACKLIST:
            print
            "  {feature}({data[Value]}) : {data[Confidence]}%".format(feature=feature, data=data)
```

Comment: Some examples: https://gist.github.com/alexcasalboni/0f21a1889f09760f8981b643326730ff

Comment: what do you mean by "I want to compare all pictures with owner and then save in dynamodb with owner name against everypicture"??

Comment: @ManojAcharya  like  Gamer is owner1 , So I want to get all pictures of owner1 from  random pictures and saved in database

Comment: @jarmod I tried face detection from this aswell. But no luck till now . any working example would be high appreciated

Comment: IndexFaces will find faces (*any* faces) in an image and add them to a Rekognition collection that you've pre-created. Do this for each of your random images. Then use SearchFacesByImage to find matches for a given image (your owner's image) in that collection. You can do this with the awscli or boto3. I'd recommend just jumping in and writing some code (it won't take much code).

Comment: @jarmod  I have a bucket , so index faces will get image from bucket and add to recognition collection  made in dynamo-db ?  and where to write then 2nd lambda function  for compare ? like I just have one file of lambda

Answer (score 1):

You can use compare_faces operation of Rekognition client. Here is a pseudocode reflecting the operation (Note: this code is not tested and only to show the concepts). You can adjust the similarity threshold as per your need.

```
client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
keyNamesInsideRandomFolder=['1.jpg','2.jpg']
for key in keyNamesInsideRandomFolder:
    response = client.detect_faces(
        'S3Object': {
           'Bucket': "bucketname",
           'Name': "randomfolder/"+key
        }
    )
    faceDetails = response['FaceDetails']
    hasFace = len(faceDetails) > 0
    if hasFace:
        response = client.compare_faces(
            SimilarityThreshold=90,
            SourceImage={
                'S3Object': {
                    'Bucket': "bucketname",
                    'Name': "ownerfolder/ownerimage.jpg"
                }
            },
            TargetImage={
                'S3Object': {
                    'Bucket': "bucketname",
                    'Name': "randomfolder/"+key
                },
            }
        )
        faceMatch= response['FaceMatches']
        similarity = faceMatch['Similarity']
        if similarity>90:
             #write to dynamodb
```

Edited: To get a list of objects from a folder with prefix/folder 'random', use list_objects operation of s3 client.

```
response = client.list_objects(
    Bucket='bucketname',
    Prefix='random'
)
numberofobjects=len(response['Contents'])
keyNamesInsideRandomFolder=[]
for x in range(1, numberofobjects):
    keyNamesInsideRandomFolder.append(response['Contents'][x]['Key'])
```

Note: The response['Contents'][x]['Key'] returns the key name of object along with the prefix. For eg. If you have an image with filename img.jpg inside random folder, it returns "random/img.jpg". Notice I started the for loop from 1 that is because the first element returned as response is just the keyname of the folder i.e "random/" in this case.

Comment: how can I get all images of a folder in this ?